# dd status=progress how to use properly

Tags: dd

I am trying to see the status of the dd command with this option "status=progress" but it says that it's an invalid status flag.

```
dd if=example.img of=/dev/sdb bs=512 conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

[Here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=af2a4ed22594badd2719c0123441d69b17bd8328) is their commit from 2014 and I do have the latest version of coreutils in Debian Jessie.  Thanks.

Comment: The coreutils version that I show in Ubuntu 15.10 is 8.23, which is older than the new status flag.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I see, version 8.24 has this new flag http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=history;f=NEWS;hb=f2ef324811cef997a7a7f41c895d2fc8febfb2c7